# Is there any option for use images in html

Tags: html

I run my angular7 project then in my home component.html. There was a error.Here is my html code:
my project is not a css.It is scss

```
<img src="assets/img/rcenter.jpg" alt="" style="width:200px;height:200px;border:0;" align="middle">
```

[image]

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: "There was a error" - what's the error? Please post the full error message.

Comment: Remove this deprecated "align" attribute.

Comment: How can i align that?There are any other options?

Comment: `There was a error` does this imply it's no longer there? What was it, anyway? Please paste error messages into your questions. As text in a *block quote*.

Comment: "Remove this deprecated "align" attribute" <- this is the error.

Comment: I pasted my code with errors.Please i want your help

Comment: @hasiniishara Remove the `align="..."` attribute, as the error message say.

Comment: Ok.I removed it.But i want align the image in to page center?

Comment: Guys, Thank you soo much for your help.Finally i do it. <img src="assets/img/rcenter.jpg" alt="" style="width:200px;height:200px;border:0;" class="center"> this is my html file and .center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
} this is my scss file

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved my problem:

```html
<img src="assets/img/rcenter.jpg" alt="" style="width:200px;height:200px;border:0;" class="center">
```

```css
.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
```